# What is difference between "for(vector<int>::iterator it=a.begin();it!=a.end();it++)" and "for(vector<int>::iterator it=a.begin();it!=a.end();++it)"

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

sometimes I see

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it=a.begin();it!=a.end();it++){
}
```

and sometimes

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it=a.begin();it!=a.end();++it){
}
```

It seems no difference when I try to print some vector to test, but not sure if it has some difference in side effect, is there any difference between them?

Comment: You copied the same snippet twice.

Comment: I see absolutely no difference, do you?

Comment: If you were to print each (it). The first It++ would show the value then increment and ++it would increment then show value. It does matter in some cases

Comment: Different operator overloads for the two!

Answer (score 1):

In your question you copied the same code, however the title indicates your confusion lies in pre-increment `(++it)` vs. post-increment `(it++)`.  There actually is an important difference here: The pre-increment operator will increment `it` and return the *incremented value*.  The post-increment operator will also increment `it` but will return the *old value*.  The same logic applies to the pre and post decrement operators `(--it)` and `(it--)`.

*However*, in a for loop, the behavior will be the same regardless of which (pre or post) you use.